# Custom payment method with redirect action then how to get order details in controller?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I'm trying to create a custom payment method with direct action as well as in magento 1

here is the code i'm trying to do the redirect after clicked "place order button"

```
 /*jshint jquery:true*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
    ],
    function ($, quote, urlBuilder, storage, errorProcessor, customer, fullScreenLoader) {
        'use strict';
        return function (messageContainer) {

            $.mage.redirect("/test/redirect"); //url is your url
        };
    }
);
```

but my question is how to get the order details in /test/redirect controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `/test/redirect/index` action you can get  the order increment id from

Checkout session `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`

Inject this class on your controller __construct function  and get data from 
`getLastOrderId`

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
 */
protected $_orderFactory;


public function __construct(
....
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
....
)
{
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}

public function orderdetails()
{
    $orderincrementId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();

    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create();    
    $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
}
```